# How to use sync token on Google People API

Tags: google-people-api

I cannot really find an example on how to use this.

Right now, I'm doing like this:

```
    // Request 10 connections.
    ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setRequestSyncToken(true)
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
            .execute();
```

I make some changes to my contacts (adding, removing, updating), then I do this:

```
    // Request 10 connections.
    ListConnectionsResponse response2 = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setSyncToken(response.getNextSyncToken())
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
            .execute();
```

But it seems like I cannot get the changes I've done earlier, not even if I do them directly from the UI. I'm pretty sure I'm using the sync token in the wrong way.

**Update (19/02/2020):** In this example I call the API requesting the sync token in the first request (I successfully get the contacts), pause the execution (by breakpoint), delete a contact and update another one (from the web page), resume the execution and then I call the API again with the sync token that I extracted from the previous call. The result is that no change was made for some reason:

```
   // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    PeopleService peopleService = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    // Request 10 connections.
    ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
            .setRequestSyncToken(true)
            .execute();

    // Print display name of connections if available.
    List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
    if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
        for (Person person : connections) {
            List<Name> names = person.getNames();
            if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + person.getNames().get(0)
                        .getDisplayName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No names available for connection.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No connections found.");
    }
    // CORRECT: 2 CONTACTS PRINTED

    // CORRECT: THE SYNC TOKEN IS THERE
    String syncToken = response.getNextSyncToken();
    System.out.println("syncToken = "+syncToken);

    // I SETUP A BREAKPOINT BELOW, I DELETE ONE CONTACT AND EDIT ANOTHER AND THEN I RESUME THE EXECUTING
    // Request 10 connections.
    response = peopleService.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
            .setSyncToken(syncToken)
            .execute();

    // Print display name of connections if available.
    connections = response.getConnections();
    if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
        for (Person person : connections) {
            List<Name> names = person.getNames();
            if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + person.getNames().get(0)
                        .getDisplayName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No names available for connection.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No connections found.");
    }
    // WRONG: I GET "NO CONNECTIONS FOUND"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I've found out is that, when requesting or setting a sync token, you must iterate the entirety of the contacts for the nextSyncToken to be populated.

That means that as long as there is a nextPageToken (wink wink setPageSize(10)), the sync token will not be populated.

You could either:

A) Loop over all the contacts using your current 
     pagination, doing whatever you need to do at every 
     iteration, and after the last call retrieve the populated 
     sync token.

B) Iterate over all the contacts in one go, using the max 
     page size of 2000 and a single personField, retrieve the 
     token, and then do whatever you need to do. Note that if 
     you are expecting a user to have more than 2000 
     contacts, you will still need to call the next pages using 
     the nextPageToken.

Here is an exemple of a sync loop, adapted from [Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync). Note that I usually use the Python client, so this Java code might not be 100% error free:

```
private static void run() throws IOException {
    Request request = people_service.people().connections()
            .list("people/me")
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses");

    // Load the sync token stored from the last execution, if any. 
    // The syncSettingsDataStore is whatever you use for storage.
    String syncToken = syncSettingsDataStore.get(SYNC_TOKEN_KEY);

    String syncType = null;

    // Perform the appropiate sync
    if (syncToken == null) {
        // Perform a full sync
        request.setRequestSyncToken(true);
        syncType = "FULL";
    } else {
        // Try to perform an incremental sync.
        request.setSyncToken(syncToken);
        syncType = "INCREMENTAL";
    }

    String pageToken = null;
    ListConnectionsResponse response = null;
    List<Person> contacts = null;

    // Iterate over all the contacts, page by page.
    do {
        request.setPageToken(pageToken);

        try {
            response = request.execute();
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            if (e.getStatusCode() == 410) {
                // A 410 status code, "Gone", indicates that the sync token is 
                // invalid/expired.
                // WARNING: The code is 400 in the Python client. I think the 
                //  Java client uses the correct code, but be on the lookout.

                // Clear the sync token.
                syncSettingsDataStore.delete(SYNC_TOKEN_KEY);
                // And anything else you need before re-syncing.
                dataStore.clear();
                // Restart
                run();
            } else {
              throw e;
            }
        }

        contacts = response.getItems();
        if (contacts.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No contacts to sync.");
        } else if (syncType == "FULL"){
            //do full sync for this page.
        } else if (syncType == "INCREMENTAL") {
            //do incremental sync for this page.
        } else {
            // What are you doing here???
        }

        pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
    } while (pageToken != null);

    // Store the sync token from the last request for use at the next execution.
    syncSettingsDataStore.set(SYNC_TOKEN_KEY, response.getNextSyncToken());

    System.out.println("Sync complete.");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Since it seems that you got how it works, can you kindly share a practical example about how to use this syncToken? I'm really confused about how should I combine `.setRequestSyncToken(true)` and `.setSyncToken(response.getNextSyncToken())`, especially when you call the APi for the first time. I'm writing a migration app and I need to make sure that my source contacts is up-to-date with Google.

Moreover, not sure if this can be useful for you or someone else, but I found out that the resourceName can change. This makes things more complicated.

Comment: Alright I'll add one later. I'm actually working on a contacts sync flask application for internal use and it was a real pain to setup.

Comment: @CapitanoGiovarco Added the exemple.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the nice example! I've read the documentation. The code for Google Calendar API is very similar to the one of People API. I have a couple of doubts nonetheless (1) how can you distinguish updated contacts from deleted contacts? My understanding is that the end up in the same pool of results (2) What should you do when your token expires? Because, if this is the case, you have no other way to sync your contact list (3) How do you handle the fact that the ResourceName can change over time?

Comment: I hope that we can keep working together, so that at the end I can post my Java code for posterity :)

Comment: For (1) and (3), the `Person` class has a metadata field of type `PersonMetadata` if `metadata` was requested in `personFields`. It contains 2 fields that are only populated on a request with a syncToken: the `previousResourseNames` field with a list of previous ids, and the `deleted` field which tells you if a contact was deleted.

Comment: (2) The proposed way to handle this (from the doc) is to do a "full sync". I opted not to relly on the token and instead use things like the last successful sync time of a user and compare it with the PersonMetadata.updateTime to know if a contact changed, assertions like "is the user new?" (doesn't has a sync time yet), and "is a contact in my datastore absent from the `.list()`". I think the updates should only be a complement that allows you to not always do a full sync.

Comment: The fields of the `Person` object are detailed here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.

On a side note, I've found that you can create your own fields by adding `UserDefined` objects to the `userDefined` field of a Person. It has a `key` and `value` field that take a non-empty string.

Comment: We received an e-mail by Google and I share a quick update with my understanding. About (3): they told me that the ResourceName used to change in some conditions but this isn't the case anymore. This doesn't explain how all our ResourceName changed after one month nonetheless.

Comment: About (1): based on your example and the one from Google, I wrote a code snippet. I confirm that the sync token is in the last page. However, my test on the usage of the token failed: I called the API requesting the sync token in the first request (I successfully got the contacts), paused the execution (by breakpoint), deleted a contact and updated another one (from the web page), resumed the execution and then I called the API again with the sync token that I extracted from the previous call. The result is that no change was made.

Comment: About (2): the updateTime in Java can be reached with `person.getMetadata().getSources()`. If I cannot work around this problem, a good idea would be the following: each time a person in our datastore changes, we save its updateTime in house. When I migrate the data to Google, I check if the updateTimes from my side are greater than the updateTimes of Google. If this is the case, I resync the contact.

Comment: The `UserDefined ` is an interesting one. I could use it to store the id of related contact in my datastore. In this way, there is a two-way connection between contacts

Comment: > "deleted a contact and updated another one". How many contacts does the test account has? If it has more than 10, then they might not be in the page you are querying. I suggest you either update one of the contacts directly in your test code, or try a bigger page size (max is 2000) if there are more than 10 contacts.

Comment: Short update: if we try to use the API directly from the browser using the sync token I printed out from our application, we receive the correct response. We receive the correct response in our app ONLY IF we hard code the value. We're troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Question: How exactly do you see what has changed using the nextSyncToken? There is no telling you which items were removed, modified and added... All you get is a list of items....